# Hourly Time Series in R, conversione

Tags: r, twitter

this should look like a dumb question but:
I am trying to plot a time series of tweets by hourly basis.
My time cell looks something like:

```
Thu Dec 05 13:27:46 +0000 2013
```

I can't figure out the way of converting it in a numerical value so to plot the convient frequency value of the tweets, by hour.

I used: as.POSIXct and as.date but always returning NA

What's wrong in something like:

```
test <- as.Date('Thu Dec 05 13:27:16 +0000 2013', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

?

Thanks to everyone :)

Vincenzo

Answer (score 1):

`strptime('Thu Dec 05 13:27:16 +0000 2013', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")`

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Can you copy paste your command you entered and the exact output?

Comment: > strptime('Thu Dec 05 13:27:16 +0000 2013', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
[1] NA

Comment: I run the exact same thing - `> strptime('Thu Dec 05 13:27:16 +0000 2013', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y") 
[1] "2013-12-05 18:57:16"`

Comment: Shot in the dark, can you try manually typing out the whole command instead of copying it?

Comment: still nothing... this is really too strange :(

Comment: finally: Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME") -> loc 
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_GB.UTF-8")

Answer (score 0):

perhapse a little late, but I had exactly the same problem.
Try:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

and then re-run your code.

Best
Simon